# Add select next match in Notepad++ (like Ctrl + D in Sublime Text)

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I am searching for a way to use the following functionality in the open source Notepad++.

In SublimeText if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> (mac: <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> I think) this happens:

- If there is no selection then the cursor position is expanded to select that word.
- Otherwise the next occurance of that word is also selected (without the need to open a search-popup).

You then have a multi-selection of words you can change, and you have actually seen each of these places (as opposed to a select-all).

Is there any way this can be done in Notepad++ (maybe with the help of Autohotkey)?

Optional: In Sublime you can also undo each of these <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>'s with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> and skip an occurance with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: From what I found in the source referenced in Tony Brix's answer, this can be done using any key combination you like, but it seems you'll need to add the functionality yourself via the NPPExec plugin (for now, at least).   I decided to finally lock horns and be done with this, so I've included the steps I used and links to the original post in an answer below.  Hopefully they will help someone who's losing their mind trying to find a solution for this common problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

I've pulled what I think is the simplest and most direct method out of the link from Tony Brix (thanks Tony).  It uses the NppExec plugin to run snippets to add each hotkey.

> **Note:** There's an NP++ plugin called *BetterMultiSelection*, but I couldn't get it to work before moving on, might be worth a look.

### Summary steps to add multi-select next match to NP++

1. Install the NppExec plugin *- NPP restart required*
2. Add a script / snippet for each hotkey you want
3. Make menu items for each script *- NPP restart required*
4. Give the menu items a key combo / hotkey

### Step 1: install The NppExec plugin

This plugin allows you to run N++ scripts directly through a console. For those unfamiliar and in a hurry, you can the install NppExec plugin by selecting.  For more info, here's the [NppExec github readme](https://github.com/d0vgan/nppexec)

1. **Plugins** > **Plugins Admin** from the menu
2. Search **NppExec**
3. ☑ **Tick it's box** and click **Install** (You'll need to restart Notepad++)

### Step 2: Add snippets for each hotkey you want

The scripts below give NP++ the multi-editing functionality of VSCode with two different shortcuts each for addNext and for skip.

> **WATCH FOR CONFLICTS:** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> was already in use for me, so you might need to watch out for this as well.  Either remove the conflicts or adjust the hotkeys provided for your environment accordingly. For key mappings, go to **Settings** > **Shortcut Mapper**.

**addNext** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg 2690  // SCI_TARGETWHOLEDOCUMENT
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS 0
sci_sendmsg 2688  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDNEXT
```

[image]

**addNextWholeWord** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg 2690  // SCI_TARGETWHOLEDOCUMENT
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS SCFIND_WHOLEWORD
sci_sendmsg 2688  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDNEXT
```

[image]

**addEach** <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg 2690  // SCI_TARGETWHOLEDOCUMENT
sci_sendmsg SCI_GETSELECTIONEMPTY
if $(MSG_RESULT) == 1 then
  sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS SCFIND_WHOLEWORD
else
  sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS 0
endif
sci_sendmsg 2689  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDEACH
sci_sendmsg 2689  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDEACH
```

[image]

**undoAddNext** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg SCI_GETSELECTIONS
set n ~ $(MSG_RESULT) - 1
sci_sendmsg SCI_DROPSELECTIONN $(n)
```

[image]

**skip** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS SCFIND_NONE
sci_sendmsg 2688  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDNEXT
sci_sendmsg SCI_GETSELECTIONS
set n ~ $(MSG_RESULT) - 2
sci_sendmsg SCI_DROPSELECTIONN $(n)
```

[image]

**skipWholeWord** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

```
NPP_CONSOLE 0
sci_sendmsg SCI_SETSEARCHFLAGS SCFIND_NONE
sci_sendmsg 2688  // SCI_MULTIPLESELECTADDNEXT
sci_sendmsg SCI_GETSELECTIONS
set n ~ $(MSG_RESULT) - 2
sci_sendmsg SCI_DROPSELECTIONN $(n)
```

*scripts and comments via bitagoras on 2020-05-04 - [src](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit/41)*

#### To save the above scripts / snippets from the console

1. <kbd>F6</kbd> or... From the menu **Plugins** > **NppExec** > **Execute**
2. **Paste in ONE** of the short “scripts” above in the **Execute** box that appears
3. (*Optionally but recommended*) test run it by pressing the OK button
4. Press <kbd>F6</kbd> again; “script” from before was retained and shows in the box
5. Press **Save** and give it a name (suggestions above each script)
6. press **OK**

> **SPEED TIP:** you'll need to *repeat these steps for each script* you want to use.  Unless you want to test one first, it's much faster to save all scripts before moving to the next step.

*steps above are summarized from user Alan Kilborn on 2020-05-21 [src](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit/46)*

### Step 3: Make menu items for each script

When one or more scripts are named and saved, they must be added to the menu so a key-combo can be assigned.

> **SPEED TIP:** Repeat for all added scripts before pressing *OK* to avoid multiple restarts (unless you wish to test one first).

1. From the menu **Plugins** > **NppExec** > **Advanced Options**.
2. In the lower left, use the **Associated Script** pulldown to select the script
3. click **Add/Modify** to add it to the list of Menu Items in the upper left  *note whether or not ☑ Place in the Macros Submenu is enabled (you will need this later).*

Once the menu items have been added... hit **OK** to apply those changes then **restart Notepad**++.

### Step 4: Give the menu items a key combo / hotkey

1. After the restart and starting from the main menu, go to **Settings** > **Shortcut Mapper** > **Plugin Commands** tab
2. **Filter by NppExec** and scroll down until you see the new script names.
3. **Click on the script** you want a keycombo for, hit **Modify**, and pick the appropriate combination of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and the selected key.

**Repeat the Modify procedure for all the scripts that you want a keycombo for.**

*steps 3 & 4, summarized from follow-up comment by PeterJones - [src](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit/47).*

### Backtracking / how to undo mistakes

*To check or confirm your list of added scripts*

- **if the macro checkbox was enabled** go to the **Macros** menu
- **if the checkbox was disabled** go to **Plugins** > **NppExec**

*If you make a mistake and / or decide to delete a script*

1. Go to **Plugins** > **NppExec** > **Advanced Options**
2. and select the item you want to delete and press the **Delete** button and exit the menu
3. Press <kbd>F6</kbd>
4. **select the script** you want to delete from the **dropdown**
5. hit **Save** to select the option for deletion *...not an intuitive step*
6. click the **Delete** button

*above as per PeterJones a comment or two later in the original thread*

Answer (score 3):

I found this thread on the Notepad++ Community page:

https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/11360/multi-selection-and-multi-edit

They are using the [python script plugin](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) to create this functionality with the following script:

```py
# this script implements the enhanced multi cursor edit functionality

def default_positions():
    return 0, editor.getLength()

def get_pos_of_bookmarks():
    npp_bookmark_marker_id_number = 24
    npp_bookmark_marker_mask = 1 << npp_bookmark_marker_id_number
    _start_position, _end_position = default_positions()
    
    line_nbr = editor.markerNext(_start_position, npp_bookmark_marker_mask)
    if line_nbr != -1:
        _start_position = editor.positionFromLine(line_nbr)
        line_nbr = editor.markerNext(line_nbr + 1, npp_bookmark_marker_mask)
        if line_nbr != -1:
            _end_position = editor.getLineEndPosition(line_nbr)
    return _start_position, _end_position

def get_pos_of_visible_lines():
    first_visible_line = editor.getFirstVisibleLine()
    _start_position = editor.positionFromLine(first_visible_line)
    lines_visible = editor.linesOnScreen()
    last_visible_line = editor.docLineFromVisible(first_visible_line+lines_visible)
    _end_position = editor.getLineEndPosition(last_visible_line)
    return _start_position, _end_position

def get_pos_of_selections():
    _start_position, _end_position = default_positions()
    if editor.getSelections() == 2:
        _start_position = editor.getSelectionNStart(0)
        _end_position = editor.getSelectionNEnd(1)
    return _start_position, _end_position


area_dict = {'a':default_positions,
             'b':get_pos_of_bookmarks,
             's':get_pos_of_selections,
             'v':get_pos_of_visible_lines}
    
editor.beginUndoAction()

def Main():
    _text = editor.getTextRange(editor.getSelectionNStart(0), editor.getSelectionNEnd(0))
    if len(_text) != 0:

        _current_position = editor.getCurrentPos()
        _current_line = editor.lineFromPosition(_current_position)
        _current_word_start_pos = editor.getLineSelStartPosition(_current_line)
        _current_word_end_pos = editor.getLineSelEndPosition(_current_line)

        find_flag = 2 # 0=DEFAULT, 2=WHOLEWORD 4=MATCHCASE 6=WHOLEWORD | MATCHCASE
        mode_options = ' 0=replace,  1=before,  2=afterwards\n'
        area_options = ' a=all, b=bookmarks, s=selected, v=visible'
        expected_results = [x+y for x in ['0','1','2'] for y in ['a','b','s','v']]
           
        result = notepad.prompt(mode_options + area_options, 'Choose the desired option', '0a')
        while result not in expected_results: 
            if result is None:
                return
            result = notepad.prompt(mode_options + area_options, 'Choose the desired option', '0a')

        chosen_mode, chosen_area = result
        area_start_position, area_end_position = area_dict[chosen_area]()
        
        if chosen_mode == '0': # replace whole string version
            editor.setEmptySelection(_current_position)       
            position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, area_start_position, area_end_position, _text)
            
            while position_tuple is not None:
                if _current_position not in position_tuple:
                    editor.addSelection(*position_tuple)
                position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, position_tuple[1], area_end_position, _text)
                    

        elif chosen_mode == '1': # insert before selected string version
            editor.setEmptySelection(_current_word_start_pos)
            position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, area_start_position, area_end_position, _text)
            
            while position_tuple is not None: 
                startpos, endpos = position_tuple
                if startpos != _current_position and endpos != _current_position:
                    editor.addSelection(startpos, startpos)
                else:
                    _current_word_start_pos, _current_word_end_pos = startpos, startpos
                position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, endpos, area_end_position, _text)


        elif chosen_mode == '2': # insert after selected string version
            editor.setEmptySelection(_current_word_end_pos)
            position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, area_start_position, area_end_position, _text)
            
            while position_tuple is not None: 
                startpos, endpos = position_tuple
                if startpos != _current_position and endpos != _current_position:
                    editor.addSelection(endpos, endpos)
                else:
                    _current_word_start_pos, _current_word_end_pos = endpos, endpos
                position_tuple = editor.findText(find_flag, endpos, area_end_position, _text)

                
        # now add the current selection
        editor.addSelection(_current_word_start_pos, _current_word_end_pos)

Main()
editor.endUndoAction()
```

Comment: Even though this script is quite weird, this is the way to go if someone needs a multiselect and has does not want to dive into Scintilla source code.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - agreed, it's not a pleasant learning curve for how ubiquitous this functionality is...  If anyone ever just wants to finally add this to NPP for themselves, I recorded the essentials from my findings below sifted out of Tony's Link.  While it's not as simple as a hotkey or a plugin like I was hoping, it's not that bad now with the info in one spot.

Answer (score 2):

You can just hit <kbd>F3</kbd> to continue searching.

Comment: Yes, but you need to use Ctrl+F before doing it.
It's the only downside, I think it's the best workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the "Select and Find Next" feature is there in Notepad++.

The key combination for this is.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

And to select the previous occurrence it is.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>

You can check it out under the **Search** menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I specifically asked that you then have a multi-selection on those words (as if you ctrl-doubleclicked on each additional selection). Example: You have the word `float`, you press the key combination now the second occurance of `float` is added to the multi selection. You can then type `double` to replace the two occurances (and keep the rest of the file unchanged)

Comment: I am not sure whether something like that is available in Notepad++. But I will let you know if I come across it or find a way to do so.

Comment: Unfortunately Ctrl + F3 only select all the same words, but you cannot edit all of them at the same time.

Comment: @ManuelDiIorio for that you need to use the replace functionality. Its under Search or you could just press Ctrl + H.

Comment: Well I found the MultiEditing feature in notepad++ and I like it!

Answer (score 0):

You can now use **Search > Find (Volatile) Next** for this feature. Default hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F3</kbd>